# How do I make a round cornered rectangular box with a domed top - for 3D printing

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

The item I am finding impossible to model is a rectangular box with rounded vertical corners, and a top which is convex in the short direction, flat in the long direction, and which transitions in a smooth round curve to meet the vertical sides. I would really appreciate some assistance.

[image]

Comment: I cant see what you exactly aiming for, but I think you can achieve it with Proportional Editing. Check out on YouTube for some quick knowledge https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+proportional+editing

Answer (score 1):

A quick, destructive approach:

[image]

1. Starting in the flat, a plane subdivided along the convex dimension
2. <kbd>O</kbd> proportional editing, spherical profile,  <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> raise the central edge / face.
3. Subdivide in the other direction
4. <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> extrude the perimeter edges downward, and  <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> flatten them
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> with  a few segments, bevel the sharp edges.
6. Maybe scale some edge loops inwards, to ease the curvature in the vicinity of the bevel

[image]

*Solidify* and *Subdivision Surface* modifiers,  for thickness, and smoothed high-resolution, for printing.

Comment: Thank you Robin. I am not new to modeling, but have used Blender only sporadically in the past. I am wanting to use it more in the future. The actual item has a protrusion from the bottom and I managed to make a solid version, but trying to make it hollow as it should be seems impossible. Subsurface seems to do nothing, and doing Solidify (it is 2.5 mm thick) ends up with self intersecting protrusions at the corners. Any tips on how to get around that.

Comment: @Dough what are the other dimensions of the box, roughly? Just so I can make you an example file.

Comment: Hold up for a (very, I hope) short time, as I have a dimension accuracy issue with the printed article.